# Check if parent page has child page of certain slug

Tags: shortcode, slug, variables, child-pages

I currently have a function that checks to see if the page is a parent, and if so, do stuff. But I also want to check to see if the parent has a child page that has a certain slug.

Basically, how would I check to see if a WordPress page has a child that matches a slug of `my-child-slug`?

In short, this is my current function:

```
/* Using Slug, make iconbox Shortcode */
function fs_sc_location_iconbox( $atts ){ 
    // begin output buffering
    ob_start();

    global $post; // if outside the loop

    $response = 'Nothing to see here';

    if ( $post->post_parent ) {
        // This is a subpage
        $slug = $post->post_name;

    } else {
        // This is not a subpage
        $slug = $post->post_name;

        // Check if has child page with slug of my-child-slug
        // ** NEED LOGIC HERE **

        // if this parent page has a child with the desired child slug...
        $response = 'Yes, this parent has a child page that we are looking for.';

    }

    // if there is a slug
    if ($slug) {
        // output the default response, unless this page is a parent of the desired child page
        echo $response;
    }
    // end output buffering, grab the buffer contents, and empty the buffer
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'fs_location_iconbox', 'fs_sc_location_iconbox' );
```

How can I updated te `// ** NEED LOGIC HERE **`  area, so that it checks if this parent page has a child of the `my-child-slug` slug? And if so, then it will set a new value for the `$response` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I was able to achieve it by adding this to my function:

```
$slug_to_check = 'my-child-slug';

// go through each child page we found
foreach( $child_pages as $child_page ) {        

    // get the slug of this child page we found
    $child_slug = $child_page->post_name;
  
    // get the link of this child page we found
    $child_link = get_page_link( $child_page->ID );
  
    // if the child page we found has the slug we want
    if($child_slug === $slug_to_check) {
      
        // output the child page link
        $response = 'Yes, this parent has a child page that we are looking for.';
    
    }  
}
```